# Putting objects in objects in ActionScript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, class, flash

I created a class of objects called `questions`, in each question there is a Question and several Answers. I would like to create a second class of objects called `games` and have several questions in each game. I would then like to have several games (with several questions) stored locally in a `sharedObject`?

Is this considered "nesting" an object within another object?

Comment: Do you mean you want to have variables for Answer objects in your Question class, or add them to Question via the Display List?

Comment: I would like that I could be able to accses this: `sampleGame.sampleQuestion.answer1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some generic code for a Game class.  It contains an array of questions.  This basically means it contains as many Question objects as you want that are accessible through the `addQuestion()` and `getQuestion()` functions.

```
public class Game {

    private var questions:Array = [];

    public function Game() {

    }

    public function addQuestion(q:Question):void {
        questions.push(question);
    }

    public function getQuestion(i:uint):Question {
        return questions[i];
    }

}
```

Likewise, here is the class for a question.  It contains a prompt, and an array of answers.  Each answer is basically just a String, so there's no real need for an Answer class.  If, however, you wanted to expand on this implementation so that each Answer also has other attributes, such as a timestamp, you could make a class for it.

```
public class Question {

    private var prompt:String;
    private var answers:Array = [];

    public function Question(prompt:String) {
        this.prompt = prompt;
    }

    public function getPrompt():String {
        return prompt;
    }

    public function addAnswer(answer:String):void {
        answers.push(answer);
    }

    public function getAnswer(i:uint):String {
        return answers[i];
    }

}
```

So to access the second answer of the first question in a game, you would write 'myGame.getQuestion(0).getAnswer(1)`.

Hope this helped.  Let me know if you have any more questions.

Comment: Thanks, How would I add several games to a `sharedObject`?